# All activities in Meta Stack Overflow vanished

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, recent-activity

I have been a member of Meta Stack Overflow for about 2 months now.  I last visited the site 14 days ago.  I very vividly remember asking a question here and being both upvoted and downvoted on it.
But my rep currently stands at 1 and there are no activity details under any of the tabs (answers, questions, votes, etc ).

Why did this happen? Were there any back-end database changes that could have impacted my previous question?

Comment: Probably your question got deleted. It happens quite frequently around here.

Comment: On your reputation tab, go to the bottom and enable "show removed posts". Does that show anything?

Comment: Please don't roll back improvements made to your posts.

Comment: @Bart or other peoples http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14949700/revisions (!)

Comment: @hayden, [that](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14949700/revisions) suggested edit (which became revision 3) was proposed at 4:15:21 (accepted 4:23:45), while revision 2 was posted at 4:15:10. So probably an edit clash, where both revision 2 and the suggested edit were based on revision 1. That said, the rollback in this very question was bad, very bad, indeed. (And so was accepting that suggested edit, but RadAl can hardly be blamed for that...)

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you just asked [this single question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160343/downvoting-without-a-comment-hard-for-people-trying-to-earn-rep) back on December 26. (Thanks [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:z7bDQB9hOQoJ:meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?page=5&sort=hot&pagesize=50%20site:meta.stackoverflow.com%20%22RadAl%22&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)!)

It had 2 upvotes and 11 downvotes, and was deleted one month later by [automatic process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/152859) that deletes questions with negative score (total upvotes - total downvotes) that has no answers.

I support such process, we really don't need to leave these around.

For those interested to see what it was, here's a copy:

> ### Downvoting without a comment. Hard for people trying to earn rep !!
>
> I know it is a duplicate of
>    [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users) , but I need to speak this out. I have been downvoted twice on this question 
>   [submitJob method in JobClient of Hadoop throws null pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761800/submitjob-method-in-jobclient-of-hadoop-throws-null-pointer/13795139#13795139) because I being a newbie , out of sheer ignorance expressed my views as an answer instead of a comment !!

Comment: Thanks @Sulf I was just about to add it myself. :)

Comment: `I support such process, ...` I support that deletion! Also, yeah, I thought you would but I tried to be faster. ;P

Comment: We're too lazy to delete those ourselves, bots are so much better for the task. ;)